# Does call to super(A, A()).__init__ depends on first parameter of super method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I came across this [thread](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2734). As suggested in the comments I tried this code

```
class WritableSerializerMethodField(serializers.SerializerMethodField):
    def __init__(self, method_name=None, **kwargs):
        self.method_name = method_name
        kwargs['source'] = '*'
        super(serializers.SerializerMethodField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        print('Data: ', data)
        return {'profile': data}
```

It did the job. I decide to replace `super(serializers.SerializerMethodField, self).__init__(**kwargs)` with `super().__init__(**kwargs)` and I got `KeyError`

```
profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
KeyError: 'profile'
```

I realised this call is different in a way that first argument to `super` is `serializers.SerializerMethodField` not `WritableSerializerMethodField`.

What difference this makes?

More simplified code:

```
class One:
    def func(self):
        print("I am parent.")


class Two(One):
    def func(self):
        print("I am child.")
```

What is the difference between `super(Two, Two())` and `super(One, Two())`?

Comment: Refer to [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two `super` calls aren't equivalent.

```
super(serializers.SerializerMethodField, self).__init__()
```

calls `__init__()` of `SerializerMethodField`'s parent - the *grandparent* of `WritableSerializerMethodField`, whereas

```
super().__init__()
```

just calls `__init__()` of `WritableSerializerMethodField`'s parent, i.e., `SerializerMethodField`.

Comment: Yea, you are right. Had to check drf source code for that :)